# Deploy Typo3 database changes

Tags: sql, database, deployment, typo3

I wonder if there is a good way of deploying database changes made on a typo3 website (on dev) to a live website?

In Magento for example there are folders containg sql install statements (for the structure, new tables etc.) and data install scripts (inserting data into the tables).
These scripts are automatically executed when deployed to live.

Good ways of getting rid of manual database adaptions are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cweiske** explained it well, for common admin it's enough to know that Install Tool has ***Database Analyser > Compare*** functionality, which is dedicated for handling DB schema differences.

Comment: Thanks. But what about any configurations you make? For ex. settings, creating nodes, sites, content elements,... Any solution for that?

Comment: No, there's no such tool - therefore as many things as possible need to be moved to files, i.e. TypoScript templates, and then just included once

Answer (score 1):

TYPO3 extensions have their `ext_tables.sql` files which define the database structure they need.

When installing the extension, the necessary database structure changes are made by the TYPO3 extension manager. You can also apply the changes yourself by using the install tool -> database update.

So as long as your extensions have the correct table definitions, you're fine and can rely on TYPO3 to update the actual database.

Comment: Thanks. But what about any configurations you make? For ex. settings, creating nodes, sites, content elements,... Any solution for that?